# Lua: How to set a variable to zero

Tags: lua, casting

I have variable that contains a number. While Lua allows variables to be set to `nil`, the variable then becomes toxic - destroying all code in its path.

If a variable contains a `nil`, I want it converted to a zero.

```
local score;
score = gameResults.finalScore;
```

I want to ensure that `score` contains a number, so I try:

```
local score;
score = tonumber(gameResults.finalScore);
```

but that doesn't work. So I try:

```
local function ToNumberEx(v)
   if (v == nil) then
      return 0
   else
      return tonumber(v)
end

local score;
score = ToNumberEx(gameResults.finalScore);
```

but that doesn't work. So I try:

```
local function ToNumberEx(v)
   if (v == nil) then
      return 0
   else
      return tonumber(v)
end

local score;
score = ToNumberEx(gameResults.finalScore);

if (score == nil) then
   score = 0
end
```

That works, but defeats the purpose of having a function.

What is wrong with the function? I'm sure there is a perfectly reasonable and logical explanation - except to anyone who is familiar with programming languages.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is about the most useless complaint ever. What does it do, how is that different from what you want it to do?

Comment: "While LUA allows variables to be set to nil, the variable then becomes toxic - destroying all code in its path." often works as a sanity check on your code, making detection of typos more obvious in most cases.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
score = tonumber(gameResults.finalScore) or 0
```

Comment: bam! I love this kind of solutions.

Answer (score 3):

> If the argument is already a number or
>   a string convertible to a number, then
>   tonumber returns this number;
>   otherwise, it returns nil.

Your code was good, except you didn't take into account what happens when gameResult.finalScore can't be converted to a number, if it was " " or "stuff" or a table than tonumber would return nil. None of your checks could detect that kind of situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to enforce that this variable `gameResults.finalScore` has this behavior (set to zero when receives any value different from a number), than you should take a look at Lua [metatables](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8).

You could create a metatable for `gameResults`, and "overwrite" the `"index"` and `"newindex"` methods of the metatable, checking the value for the `finalScore` field, and thus enforcing it's value to be on the desired ranges.

Not the best solution, but depending on your case, could be a good defensive practice against some other *"evil developer"* on the team. :-)

www.lua.org/pil/13.html (I'm not currently allowed to post more than 1 link) PiL 1 can help too, if you are still using Lua 5.0 or you want a more deep understanding of the metatables concept.